# How to track words with special characters using streamR package in R?

Tags: r, twitter, stream

I am using streamR package to stream some tweets but It's not working with some portuguese words like "polícia", "médico", "audiência" and "política", etc. If I use "policia" instead, It only shows tweets containing "policia", in spanish, It doesn't show "polícia" in portuguese.

I'm under R 3.1, Windows 7, streamR 0.2.1. Here is the piece of code:

```
> filterStream(file="acento.json", track="polícia", timeout=60, oauth=twitCred)
Capturing tweets...
Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 61 seconds with up to 4 tweets downloaded.
> df <- parseTweets("acento.json")
Error in readLines(tweets, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  5 arguments passed to .Internal(readLines) which requires 6
```

This message showing that 4 tweets were found looks like a default message, because the json file generated never exceeds 1kb.

```
> filterStream(file="acento1.json", track="política", timeout=60, oauth=twitCred)
Capturing tweets...
Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 62 seconds with up to 4 tweets downloaded.
> df <- parseTweets("acento1.json")
Error in readLines(tweets, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  5 arguments passed to .Internal(readLines) which requires 6
```

Could someone please give me a hint of how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

try this for **polícia**:

`filterStream(file="acento.json", track="pol\u00edcia", timeout=30, oauth= twitCred)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly! Special characters represented in unicode...very well thought out.
I spent hours on this.