# R readLines error

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to work with filterStream() in r. I am able to get the tweets and save them in a JSON file but while parsing the stored tweets using parseTweets() I get the following error:

Error in readLines(tweets, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  5 arguments passed to .Internal(readLines) which requires 6

this is the sample code:

```
filterStream(file="tweets.json",track=term, timeout=60,oauth=twitCred,language="en")
Capturing tweets...
Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 60 seconds with up to 45 tweets downloaded.
> tweets.df <- parseTweets("tweets.json", simplify = 'TRUE')
Error in readLines(tweets, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  5 arguments passed to .Internal(readLines) which requires 6
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147090/how-to-track-words-with-special-characters-using-streamr-package-in-r suggests there may be an issue with accented letters or other special characters in `term`

Comment: @Henry here is what term has term<-c("cwc15","india","wewontgiveitback")